# how to share information , which is in a device tree node, among different drivers

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am  writing an RTC driver which will access info from DT node named RTC.
However i also need to access SPI in the same driver.
The Virtual addresss base to access SPI is being used in several drivers.
how do i share info from SPI-DT node between several drivers without any conflict.?

Comment: *"The Virtual addresss base to access SPI is being used in several drivers"* -- By *"SPI"* are you referring to a SPI Master Controller?  Why would anything but the Master Controller driver need this address?  What are these other drivers? Do  these other drivers adhere to the standard Linux SPI model?  Study https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/spi/spi-summary

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to dumpster dive for information in parent nodes, but you probably do not want to do that.

The SPI controller's registers should only be used by the SPI bus driver. Devices on that bus should only rely on `spi_read`/`spi_write` or similar (from `<linux/spi/spi.h>`). This means that you can reuse the RTC driver on a different board with a different SPI controller.

If there is no driver available for your controller, start with writing that. Have a look at a simple one, e.g. `drivers/spi/spi-altera.c`. *NOTE*: Many drivers reuse functionality from the SPI bitbang implementation in Linux. This does *not* mean that these controllers use bitbanging I/O, it is simply a naming idiosyncrasy of Linux's SPI subsystem.

The devices that use the SPI bus would then be children of the controller's device node, with their `reg` properties denoting which chip select to activate to reach the desired device. The standard bindings are documented in `Documentation/devicetree/bindings/spi/spi-bus.txt`.